Is it possible to use voice commands in Ubuntu like copy, paste etc
I do a lot of editing and it would help a lot if I could voice command for copy and paste when I select a text. Is it possible to do that in Ubuntu?

What research have you done to solve this? What version of Ubuntu are you speaking of?

Latest version. I did some google search but can't find any result.

Seems you have answered your own question.

So, it's not possible? Why?

Are you aware that on Linux systems, including Ubuntu, as soon as you have selected something, you have copied it. No need for anything other than selecting. Just select, and then use your middle mouse button to paste. So if you still need to select in order to issue your voice command, are you sure it is worth it? You already have the thing selected and your hand on the mouse, and you need the mouse to switch focus onto whatever it is you want to paste in, so I can't imagine how a voice command could be faster or easier than a middle click.

I didn't know that. Thank you.

This question is similar to: How do I disable middle mouse button click paste?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
